# Displaying Aggregated results in PHP from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to display aggregated results in PHP from Elasticsearch. I want my output to be something like this:

> Date : how many records have that date
>
> 20110105 : 5 records
>
> 20120501 : 2 records
>
> 20120602 : 15 records

This is what I have so far:

```
    $json = '{"aggs": { "group_by_date": { "terms": { "field": "arrivalDate" } } } }';

        $params = [
            'index' => 'pickups',
            'type' => 'external',
            'body' => $json 
            ];
        
$results = $es->search($params);
```

How do I display the number of records for each date?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [date histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) for your purpose.
Your query will look like -

```
{
    "query": #if any,
    "aggs": {
        "date": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "fieldName",
                "interval": "day",
                "min_doc_count": 1 #if you need key with any minimum doc count
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

> To run this query correctly, your date field type should be `date`. Otherwise, you will get an error.

Hope this helps

Comment: here I am assuming that your field type is 'date'